# My comment was deleted while an identical, later posted comment was kept?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-user

The post in question is: [Mathematical Expression of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764910/)

I had commented that the question was a duplicate question and then provided the link. A few minutes later another user makes an analogous comment. When the post was closed, my comment was deleted and the other user's kept.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your flag comment (about the duplicate) was automatically deleted by the [community bot](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) when the question was closed as a duplicate. The other comment presumably used a format that the software didn't recognize (and therefore didn't delete) during the clean-up.

Comment: Isn't it just that the system creates a comment at the first duplicate-flag, and then deletes precisely that comment upon closure (not based on the content, but the very fact that it was system-created)?

Comment: Sounds plausible.